# In Fantasy Sports, is it proven that first pick tends to win the league most often?

Tags: american-football, nfl, fantasy

Since most leagues use the ["snake style"](http://www.draftstreet.com/fantasy/football/how-does-a-snake-draft-fantasy-football-league-work/) draft, there are positives and negatives to picking first, or last. First pick gets the **First overall** pick in the draft, but then has to wait until the **last pick** of the 2nd round. Then once again they get first pick in the 3rd round.

On the other hand, last pick in the first round gets to pick first in the 2nd round - therefore they get two successive picks.

It generally seems that most people consider the first pick the best for your chances of winning obviously, I just wanted to see if stats backed that up entirely.

*Is there any historical fantasy data to help prove which pick position tends to win the most?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [article](http://fantasyfootballcompanion.com/draft-position.html) indicates (through an analysis of 100 leagues across several sites), that there is *not* a strong correlation between picking first or last and winning your league.

[image]

This chart shows that most often the winner was in the 7th position. However I would not take the results as conclusive one way or the other. But I would say that there is not a strong correlation between draft position and overall results in a fantasy league.

Comment: I will say that first pick is really rough. I picked first this year and I can tell you, going first in round one and then last in round 2, even if you get 2 picks in a row is brutal.